# Can Detect Collision but bodies pass through phaser p2 physics

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

For some reason in my game i can detect collisions but bodies are actually not colliding they are passing through.

This is how i create player:

```
function createPlayer () {
    player = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'playerimg');
    player.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.physics.p2.enableBody(player, true);     
    player.body.data.shapes[0].sensor = true;
    game.camera.follow(player);
    player.body.onBeginContact.add(player_coll, this); 

    console.log(player.body)
}
```

player_coll function fires perfectly fine on collision.

```
var tree_object = function (id, type, startx, starty, value) {
    this.id = id; 
    this.posx = startx;  
    this.posy = starty; 
    this.tree = game.add.sprite(this.posx, this.posy, 'tree');
    this.tree.type = 'tree';
    this.tree.id = id;
    game.physics.p2.enableBody(this.tree, true);
    this.tree.body_size = 10; 
    this.tree.body.data.gravityScale = 0;
    this.tree.body.data.shapes[0].sensor = true;


}





  function player_coll(body,test){
    if(body.sprite.type=="tree"){
    console.log(body)
    console.log("collided with tree")
    }



    }
```

My preload function:

```
function preload(){

    game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true; // mouse browserdan çıkınca uyutma.2 ekran test için.
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, gameProperties.gameWidth, 
    gameProperties.gameHeight);
    //Fizik için P2JS kullanıcaz.
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    //fizik dünyasının sınırlarını yaratır.(duvarlar)
    game.physics.p2.setBoundsToWorld(true, true, true, true, true)
    //Y nin yerçekimini 0 a eşitle böylece yere düşmeyecek.
    game.physics.p2.gravity.y = 0;
    // Yerçekimini tamamen kapat.
    game.physics.p2.applyGravity = false; 
    game.physics.p2.enableBody(game.physics.p2.walls, false); 
     game.load.image('playerimg', '/assets/player.png');
     game.load.image('background', 'assets/lake.png');   

     game.load.image("wood", "/assets/wood.png");
     game.load.image("tree", "/assets/tree.png");

    // Collision(çarpma) detectionu aç.
    game.physics.p2.setImpactEvents(true);


}
```

[image]

As you see in the picture why they are passing through ?

Comment: Have you tried sprite specific collision functions such as sprite1.body.collides(sprite2)? How are you moving the character? Just changing sprite.body.x?

Comment: yes i am doing that just changing body.x

Comment: Do i have to use velocity for collisions to work ? Game is online i got some weird results when i used velocity to move player.I will update my question after more trials.

Comment: even with velocity it move throughs (for somereason if i use velocity my player teleports after waiting a while.I guess velocity never sets to 0 in server so even if i press right key once it adds 10 to velocity and player keeps moving and then if i press again server updates client with new position so it looks like its teleported

Comment: by changing body.x, you are actually "teleporting" sprites, so collision would not work. So velocity or accelerations are usually used, but your game seems like a tilemap game. Player would either move to next tile or not, never in between. Right? Then acceleration and velocity are not for this.

Comment: I'm concerned that phaser's collision physics would not work in your game if you are expecting it to move binary-like. (like x = 1, 2, 3... not like 1.1, 2.3, 3.15..) That case, you need to write your own code to perform "collision".